# How to add a radio button into a stackpanel from another Window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to wpf and c#. I have two windows like MainWindow and MainWindow2.
I have a button in MainWindow that opens the MainWindow2 and a GroupBox with a StackPanel.
In the MainWindow2 I have a button that I want to add a RadioButton to the StackPanel in the MainWindow.

Here's the MainWindow code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RadioButton butãoRadial = new RadioButton();
        stackPanel1.Children.Add(butãoRadial);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow2 obj = new MainWindow2();
        obj.Show();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

Here's the MainWindow2 Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow2 : Window
{
    public MainWindow2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();

    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english ^^

Comment: Are you wanting to add the radio button to the original mainwindow or the one you create in MainWindow2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not do it that way.... every time you add controls directly to a window from another window a kitten dies. If you're not into kittens then substitute something else you hold dear into that sentence.

A more appropriate way to do this is to bind an [ItemsControl](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) (or a derivative like a [ListView](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/)) to an `ObservableCollection` in your ViewModel, then use an `DataTemplate` defined in the `ItemTemplate` property to represent each item in the ObservableCollection on the screen. Then all you have to do is add the appropriate data item to the ObservableCollection (which can be passed to the second window).

Pleeeeeeeeaaaassssseee don't be adding controls from another window!